# ABB S203-C25 25A per line or total

Tags: power

I am completely new to EE. I have ABB S203-C25 curcuit breaker installed. My question is 25A is per line (i.e. total 75, or 25A is total limit)?

Comment: I would check the datasheet.

Comment: The questions about building wiring are a better fit on DIY.SE (home improvement stack).

Comment: There is nothing in the datasheet. (or probably, it is hidden somewhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That device is effectively three 25 Amp circuit breakers mechanically tied together.  All three poles  will trip if the current on any pole exceeds 25 Amps.

Answer (score 1):

Each pole can carry 25A.

That's just how 3-phase breakers are rated.